# Formula for Transposing Specific Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out if there is a formula that can transpose specific columns in a Google sheet.

I have created a data entry tab for users to input data "Input (Data Entry)" (screenshot below), the yellow highlighted column names are the fields that need to be transposed in the output data set.

[image]

My goal is to have the data input transform into a formatted data set seen in the "Output (Dataset)" (screenshot below). The yellow highlighted column is the transposed column compiled from the columns in the "Input (Data Entry)" tab. Fields highlighted in orange are fields that are imported from the "Input (Data Entry)" tab, fields highlighted in blue are duplicated entries of the orange fields due to transposed values. Do note for Field 5A - Field 5C, these values essentially repeat thus why they are highlighted in orange.

[image]

I have attempted to link the sheet and use transpose on the specific columns but problems arises when I try to copy the formula downwards as the reference rows from the input sheet would jump in the formulas due to spacing created by the transposed values. Is there a formula workaround for this?

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CrbzefxMwMtPHiqCW0-Hg94yXbZk6i9DmrsAwQx62z8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REDUCE to process those three columns, and stack the retrieved other columns based on the rows of each cell:

```
=REDUCE({'Input (Data Entry)'!A1:F1,'Input (Data Entry)'!I1:M1},'Input (Data Entry)'!F2:H5,LAMBDA(a,v,
VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX('Input (Data Entry)'!A:E,ROW(v)),v,INDEX('Input (Data Entry)'!I:M,ROW(v))))))
```

[image]

The first part are the headers, you can grab other cells or just type them inside: for example, change `{'Input (Data Entry)'!A1:F1,'Input (Data Entry)'!I1:M1}` with `HSTACK("header 1, "header 2"....., "header 11")`

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your solution this is what I am looking for. However, I realized for the final output data set I need to have 2 separate transposed columns that are transposed from 2 sets of columns in the "Input (Data Entry)". (I have updated the screenshots and sample file) in the initial post to reflect this. I have attempted to modify your formula but can't figure out how to modify the "'Input (Data Entry)'!F2:H5" portion of the formula so that I transpose the 2nd set of columns from the "Input (Data Entry)" tab in the output tab as well.

Comment: OK, here it goes a modified version: =REDUCE({'Input (Data Entry)'!A1:E1,'Input (Data Entry)'!H1:I1,'Input (Data Entry)'!L1:P1},'Input (Data Entry)'!E2:F5,LAMBDA(a,v,
VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX('Input (Data Entry)'!A:D,ROW(v)),v,INDEX('Input (Data Entry)'!H:H,ROW(v)),OFFSET(v,0,4),INDEX('Input (Data Entry)'!L:P,ROW(v))))))

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for taking you time to work on this. Haven't come across the HSTACK and VSTACK functions before, will take a look more into this after this.